# Viewpager with listview & listview header bug

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

i use a viewpager with 3 fragments as pages. The first fragment has a listview & a listview header. I add the listview header like so:

```
  View headerView; //defined at the beggining of the class

  if (headerView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //item layout
            int viewID = R.layout.listview_header;
            headerView = mInflater.inflate(viewID, null);
        }
  listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

The problem is that when i swipe between the pages and then come back to the first fragment(with the listview header), the header is dublicated(x2 the header views).

I understand that when the viewpager recreates the first fragment it add a second time the header. How can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void addHeader() {
          View header = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
          TextView tvValue = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);

          tvValue.setText("Leads");

          tvValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fffb8900"));
          getListView().addHeaderView(header,null,false);
         }
```

Comment: It worked. Just a small note, it won't work with the FragmentStatePagerAdapter but with FragmentPagerAdapter instead. Thanks!

Comment: if(getListView().getAdapter()==null){    getListView().addHeaderView(header,null,false);}